# Why doesn't CSS have the ability for elements to preserve width:height ratio

Tags: css, syntax, scaling

So, this is perhaps foolish, but it seems to me that CSS would benefit from the ability to do something similar to the following:

```
.some-element {
    width:100%;
    height:50% of width;
}
```

But attributes can't reference other attributes or variables.  This isn't an incredibly common use-case, but it happens often enough that I wonder why something as simple as ratio-based heights don't exist.  Elements like `img` already do this, yet others can't.

**EDIT** (To try and clarify what I'm trying to find out)

Is there something about CSS as a language that prevents it from having syntax like this, or is it this way just because this feature was simply not added?

Comment: For those voting to close: I am asking why CSS, as a language can't handle syntax like this.  How is that against the format of the site?

Comment: The problem is that, by the nature of your question, it can not be answered here.

Comment: @Indigenuity Per the site's flagging menu: "**Not Constructive**: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by **facts**, **references**, or **specific expertise**, but **this** question will likely **solicit debate**, **arguments**, **polling**, or **extended discussion**". Please pay close attention to the bold words. I agree this question is good for debate, but not for this site however. This is because there is no _right_ or _wrong_ answer to this question. Therefore it is by the site's definition **not constructive**.

Comment: What about `width: 0.5 * height; height: 0.5 * width` as a reason for this not being possible?

Comment: Is the edited question preferrable, then?

Comment: @Indigenuity you are still soliciting a debate, not an answer. Again, I agree this is an interesting topic and something I had not thought about before. I would definitely like to see a discussion on this as well. However, the question still provides no means of determining a right or wrong answer and therefore is **not constructive**. It is simply not a good fit for the _Q&A_ format of this site.

Comment: @Eric In that case, the particular syntax I chose is bad, but the concept is still there.  Perhaps it would require a new attribute so width and height don't refer to each other.  In any case, thanks for posting an actual response.

Comment: @War10ck In the interest of making this question answerable, and for future questions, how would you change this?  I am asking about why CSS doesn't include the capability of preserving ratios of height:width for elements besides `img` tags.  Specifically, whether there is something about the nature of CSS as a language that makes this impossible.  Now, there may not be one, single answer only, but there are certainly factual, non-opinionated answers available for this question, as Eric has shown.

Comment: The W3C has balked at adding anything dynamic to CSS since forever.  CSS authors have been begging for variables for as long as I can remember.  I'm honestly shocked that we have the `calc()` function or the ability to set content equal to an attribute (`content: attr(title)`).

Answer (score 3):

You can [use an image](http://jsfiddle.net/zMa7Q/1/) to make a div follow the same rules:

```
<div>
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
</div>
```

```
div img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 250px;
}
```

In that example, the div is square

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I'm looking more for why CSS can't handle this, rather than workarounds, though.  Perhaps I should reword the question?